# how to print a tuple of tuples without brackets

Tags: python, tuples

I am trying to print the tuple `new_zoo` given below without brackets:

```
zoo=('python','elephant','penguin')
new_zoo=('monkey','camel',zoo)
```

I know usually we can use `', '.join(...)`. But because here the `new_zoo` tuple contains a inside tuple zoo, so when I use `', '.join(new_zoo)` it shows:

```
TypeError: sequence item 2: expected str instance, tuple found
```

Can anyone help me with this question?

Comment: You can just add the tuples together: `new_zoo=('monkey','camel') + zoo`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to add the tuples instead of nesting them:

```
>>> new_zoo = ('monkey', 'camel') + zoo
```

Another way to create a flattened tuple is to use star unpacking (colloquially known as splat sometimes):

```
>>> new_zoo = ('monkey', 'camel', *zoo)
>>> print(new_zoo)
('monkey', 'camel', 'python', 'elephant', 'penguin')
```

You can assemble the string directly in this case: `', '.join(new_zoo)`.

If you need to process a nested tuple, the most general way would be a recursive solution:

```
>>> new_zoo = ('monkey', 'camel', zoo)
>>> def my_join(tpl):
...    return ', '.join(x if isinstance(x, str) else my_join(x) for x in tpl)
>>> my_join(new_zoo)
monkey, camel, python, elephant, penguin
```

Answer (score 4):

First, you are adding `zoo` to your tuple `new_zoo`. You should unwrap it to extend `new_zoo` instead.

```
zoo = ('python', 'elephant', 'penguin')
new_zoo = ('monkey', 'camel', *zoo) # ('monkey', 'camel', 'python', 'elephant', 'penguin')
```

Then for printing, one clean way to do is to unwrap your tuple in `print` and provide a separator.

```
print(*new_zoo, sep=', ')
# prints: monkey, camel, python, elephant, penguin
```

If you want to store the printed string, there you can use `str.join`.

```
new_zoo_string = ', '.join(new_zoo) # 'monkey, camel, python, elephant, penguin'
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to join the contents of `zoo` as well:

```
zoo=('python','elephant','penguin')
new_zoo=('monkey','camel',','.join(zoo))
final_zoo = ','.join(new_zoo)
```

Output:

```
'monkey,camel,python,elephant,penguin'
```

However, you can also iterate over the contents of `new_zoo` and apply `str.join`:

```
zoo=('python','elephant','penguin')
new_zoo=('monkey','camel',zoo)
final_zoo = ','.join([i if not isinstance(i, tuple) else ','.join(i) for i in new_zoo])
```

Output:

```
'monkey,camel,python,elephant,penguin'
```

Answer (score 2):

> TypeError: sequence item 2: expected str instance, tuple found

As the error message says: The item 2 in `new_zoo` (remember to start counting from 0, so it's the last item) needs to be of str type for `join`, but it is a tuple instead.

It seems that you want to extend your `zoo` tuple, but you're plugging it as an item into `zoo` instead. So to speak, you're putting a box into another box, instead of the items in the first box into the second one.

You probably meant to do something like this:

```
new_zoo=('monkey','camel')+zoo
```

Answer (score 0):

Just track the tuple and then use recursion , Now no matter how many nested tuple you have :

```
zoo=('python','elephant','penguin')
zoo1=('example1','example2',zoo)
zoo2=('example3','example4',zoo1)
new_zoo=('monkey','camel',zoo2)

def flat_tuple(tuple_s):
    final=[]
    for i in tuple_s:
        if isinstance(i,tuple):
            final.extend(flat_tuple(i))
        else:
            final.append(i)

    return final


for sub in flat_tuple(new_zoo):
    print(sub)
```

output:

```
monkey
camel
example3
example4
example1
example2
python
elephant
penguin
```

Answer (score 0):

```python
zoo = ('python', 'elephant', 'penguin')
new_zoo = ('monkey', 'camel', zoo)


# One liner
print(', '.join(map(lambda x: x if isinstance(x, str) else ', '.join(x) if hasattr(x, '__iter__') else str(x), new_zoo)))

# Recursive and powerful
def req_join(x):
    if isinstance(x, str):
        return x
    elif hasattr(x, '__iter__'):
        return ', '.join(map(req_join, x))
    else:
        return str(x)
big_zoo = ('cat', new_zoo, range(5), 'dog', 123, ('lev1', ('lev2', ('lev3', ('lev4', ('lev5', range(5)))))))
print(req_join(big_zoo))
```